# Angularjs version 1.5 fails when I load jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I use jquery-2.0.3.min.js and js/angularjs 1.6.1 from https://angularjs.org
It works OK.
Now I wanted to add ui bootstrap (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).
But when I load it i get and error that $.angular.cps is undefined (and it does not load the angular), so I copied the exact header from the example

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.4.0.js"></script>
<script src="example.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This works (in the demo). But when I add the jQuery

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
```

It fails to load the angular
It crashes in line 4511 in angular.js:

```
throw $injectorMinErr('unpr', "Unknown provider: {0}", path.join(' <- '));
```

The error:

`[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=%24routeProvider`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS and jQuery conflict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28064784/angularjs-and-jquery-conflict)

Comment: I believe angular only supports jquery 2.1 and above

Comment: I think you need to load jq first

Comment: Are you using `$routeProvider` in your code? It's a provider in `ngRoute`. I don't see any reference to `angular-route.js` in your example.