# get width of css class in angular at run time

Tags: html, css, angular, width

I need to get the width of a css class in my angular component at the run time

```
<div class="document-section"></div>
```

I can't seems to get it by trying any of these:

```
$('.document-section').width()
$('.document-section').attr('width')
```

with error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).width is not a function
>       at :1:22

Can anyone help me with this?
Thank you

Comment: try this code    $('.document-section').css('width', '200px');

Comment: What Angular version are you using?

Comment: Could be conflicts. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28064784/angularjs-and-jquery-conflict

Comment: I am not setting the width to use .css('width', '200px') even I tried $('.document-section').css('width') and  same error as above

Comment: @Gezzasa angular 4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get width of (DOM) Element in Angular2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39084250/how-to-get-width-of-dom-element-in-angular2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the width of the class at runtime you need to first make sure it is drawn/rendered in the view.

So whatever your code to get the width should be included in the `ngAfterViewInit()` life cycle hook.

You dont specifically need to get it from css class just use `ViewChild` in the div and get it's width.

**HTML**

```
<div #documentSection class="document-section"></div>
```

**TS**

```
@ViewChild("documentSection")
private documentSection: ElementRef;

private divWidth: number;

public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   this.divWidth = this.documentSection.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
}
```

Comment: can you help me more with the ViewChild in the div?

Comment: Added a small example